# Python pandas- datetime for Peak hour and peak off Hour analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a df like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datatime = [('2019-09-15 00:15:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 00:30:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 00:45:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:00:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:15:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:30:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:45:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 02:00:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 02:15:00.000000000')]
p =[494.76,486.36,484.68,500.64,482.16,483.84,483.0,478.8,493.08,474.6]
q = [47.88,33.6,41.16,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(datatime,p,q)), columns = [['datetime','p','q']])
df
```

I am doing an analysis for 30 days by grouping my data into on-peak and off-peak hours. For this I also need to identify the days of the week. I tried use the `pandas` function:

```
df.dt.day_name()
```

But in this particular case it is not feasible since for this function the day start at `00:00:00` and at my program I need it to start at `00:15:00`.
Since I have 96 points for each day, I thought about using a dictionary:

```
days_of_the_week = {'Sunday': 1,'Monday': 2,'Tuesday': 3, 'Wednesday': 4, 'Thursday':5, 'Friday':6 , 'Saturday':7}
```

How can I apply it to my df so that every 96 points a new day is identified?

Comment: What would the expected output be for the provided input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add an offset using a [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html?highlight=timedelta#pandas.Timedelta) object when calculating the weekday. This won't affect the values of the `datetime` column.

```
In [21]: dt_index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-01 23:45:00', periods=96)

In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dt_index, np.random.rand(len(dt_index))), columns=['datetime', 'whatever'])

In [24]: df.tail()
Out[24]:
              datetime  whatever
91 2022-01-01 22:45:00  0.910446
92 2022-01-01 23:00:00  0.199106
93 2022-01-01 23:15:00  0.051808
94 2022-01-01 23:30:00  0.799284
95 2022-01-01 23:45:00  0.584663

In [25]: df['weekday'] = (df.datetime.astype('datetime64[ns]') + pd.Timedelta(seconds=15*60)).dt.day_name()

In [26]: df.tail()
Out[26]:
              datetime  whatever   weekday
91 2022-01-01 22:45:00  0.910446  Saturday
92 2022-01-01 23:00:00  0.199106  Saturday
93 2022-01-01 23:15:00  0.051808  Saturday
94 2022-01-01 23:30:00  0.799284  Saturday
95 2022-01-01 23:45:00  0.584663    Sunday
```

Just a note on the way you constructed you `DataFrame`.

`df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(datatime,p,q)), columns = [['datetime','p','q']])`

The use of `list` is unnecessary and could impede performance for larger data sets. Additionally, you shouldn't use the the nested list for the `columns` argument as it has unintended effects.

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(datatime,p,q)), columns = [['datetime','p','q']])

In [28]: type(df.datetime)
Out[28]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(datatime, p, q), columns=['datetime','p','q'])

In [30]: type(df.datetime)
Out[30]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: Thank your for the help. I need to pd.Timedelta(seconds=-15*60)) but this function really solve this problem, and also thank your for the tip about the zip list